# How to set date range in datepicker android from JSON data (webservice)?

Tags: android, datepicker

sorry maybe I'm still newbie and I'm stack about datepicker in android. I have data from android that is date range of registration like this:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "13-06-2017"
        },
        {
            "date": "14-06-2017"
        },
        {
            "date": "15-06-2017"
        },
        {
            "date": "16-06-2017"
        },
        {
            "date": "17-06-2017"
        },
        {
            "date": "19-06-2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to create date picker only displaying active date based JSON data above? Can you help me. I've search tutorials but still not found.

Comment: What do you mean by active dates? Like today?

Comment: I mean active date are the date list from JSON data which clickable / selectable